# Pulling value from string with RegEx

Tags: javascript

I have the string

```
text ='something here width="560" something here'
```

and I would like to pull out the width value.  I tried

```
width = text.match(/width=\"[^\"]/g);
```

but that just returns an array with one value `= 5`.  Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
var m = text.match(/width="([^"]+)/);
var width = m && m[1];
```

Note the `+` — a character class will only match one character by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
/width=\"[^\"]+/g
              ^--- + means 1 or more
```

Without quantifier it matches exactly one character.

Comment: @minitech: it's not a ready to use code, but an extraction :-)